# How to restore a mysql DB from frm, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a corrupted HD that hosted a mysql DB.

I was able to copy the mysql folder and recover the DB structure by reading the .frm files with mysqlfrm utilities.

Now I need to recover the real data. Is there a way to do it from files inside the mysql folder?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try everything at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/recover-innodb-mysql/?

Comment: See here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54007/mysql-backup-from-ibdata1-ib-logfile1-ib-logfile0

Comment: I tried, but after doing it, i'm no more able to restart mysql service; probably, what I have in my 'recovered mysql folder' doens't suit my 'current mysql installation'

Answer (score 0):

Copy the **`data`** directory mysql for backup.
Stop mysql service.
Paste these in data directory.

Start myssql service.

Comment: I tried, but after doing it, i'm no more able to restart mysql service; probably, what I have in my 'recovered mysql folder' doens't suit my 'current mysql installation'

Comment: do you have the whole backup directory, or only these 3 files?

Comment: I have the whole directory